# Device Token null when deploying app as ad-hoc (Urban Airship)

Tags: objective-c, push-notification, apple-push-notifications, urbanairship.com, devicetoken

I implemented the Urban Airship library into my application and I can successfully send push notifications to a specific device **in development mode**. After startup I get the device token and save it into a mysql database. However, when I use the app in ad-hoc mode, the device token is always `(null).`

`APP_STORE_OR_AD_HOC_BUILD` is set to `YES`

and the APP Key and APP-Secret for both production and development are correct.

Any ideas how to get the device token in ad-hoc/appstore mode?

---

Edit:
Identical question has been posted in the [Urban Airship Forum](https://support.urbanairship.com/customer/en/portal/questions/883785-device-token-null-when-deploying-app-as-ad-hoc?new=883785).

Comment: during installation does it asks with the alert of using push notification?

Comment: No, but it did the first time in developer mode.

Comment: have you updated the adhoc/distribution certificates at the urbanairship control panel ?

Comment: do you get any pushnotifications with distribution certs ? and have you updated the plist with appkey and appsecrets at mobile end ?

Comment: @yunas, when i copy the application to my phone with XCode, it works. When I use a distribution tool such as TestFlight, then it doesn't work.

Comment: make sure that the build you create for Testflight and upload is via distribution cert and provisioning.

Comment: this is also already the case :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For me also same thing happened. What we did to solve problem is just recreated new adHoc provisioning profile. Then we got alert asking to install push notification. Its one of the major issue in iOS push notification. We must configure push nofitiation SSL certificate before creating provisioning profile.

Comment: Thanks for this. I will try to re-create the adhoc-provisioning profile. What do you mean with: "We must configure push notification in 'APP ID' before creating provisioning profile."?

Comment: I mean we must configure push nofitiation SSL certificate before creating provisioning profile.